# arraylist is not printing first element

Tags: java

I am trying to write some java code, but I am getting an Exception. 
my problem is that I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to add athlete
the program is to accept athletes and the calculate score average
Here is my code

```
public class AthleteTest {

        final int  MAX_ATHELETE = 200;
        private int count=0;    
        Athlete[] at = new Athlete[MAX_ATHELETE];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void addAthletes(){
            char add = 'Y';
            while(add == 'Y'){

                System.out.println("name:");
                String name = sc.nextLine();
                at[count].setName(name);

                //Get athlete's Id number
                System.out.println("id :");
                int id = sc.nextInt();
                at.setId(id);

                //sc.nextLine();

                count++;


                System.out.println("Would you like to add another athlete?   Y / N");
                add = Character.toUpperCase(sc.next().charAt(0));
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }


    my Athlete class is as follow

    public class Athlete {

        private String name;
        private int id;

        private double [] grades;

        public Athlete(){
            this.name = null;
            this.id= 0;
        }

        public Student(String name, int id){
            this.name = name;
            this.id= id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is ArrayList?

Comment: `at[count].setName(name)` - is `at[count]` initialized? If it's not, that's why you get `NullPointerException`. You should do `at[count] = new Athlete()` first

Comment: Yes, I did, but it is still giving me a null pointer exception

Comment: public void addAthletes(){
            char add = 'Y';
            while(add == 'Y'){

                System.out.println("name:");
                String name = sc.nextLine();
                at[count].setName(name);

                //Get athlete's Id number
                System.out.println("id :");
                int id = sc.nextInt();
                at.setId(id);

                //sc.nextLine();

                count++;

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the exception because you're trying to access athletes object before instantiating them. With this initialization:

```
 Athlete[] at = new Athlete[MAX_ATHELETE];
```

You've merely created a place to hold Athlete instances.

Change your in-loop code this way:

```
System.out.println("name:");
String name = sc.nextLine();
at[count] = new Athlete(); // Add this line
at[count].setName(name);
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have added that line but I am still getting the the same null pointer  exception

Comment: The `NullPointerException` always tells you the class and the line where the error occurs. Check what's in this line and you'll know what's wrong (or at least what variable needs to be initialized)